# Как организовать вызов AlertDialog из класса без активити?

Tags: android, java

Есть онлайн-приложение. В нем куча активити из которых надо отправлять HTTP-запросы к серверу. Для этого сделан отдельный класс - HttpLoader, через который удобно делать эти самые запросы. Использование выглядит примерно так:

```
HttpLoader loader = new HttpLoader("http://site.com/script.php");
loader.setOnFinishListener(new HttpLoader.OnFinishListener() {
    public void onFinish(JSONObject json) {
        //Обработка данных
    }
});
loader.start();
```

Хотелось бы показывать AlertDialog, если вдруг пропало соединение с сетью, с двумя кнопками - "Повторить попытку" и "Выйти из приложения". Проблема в том, что в этом классе нет ссылки на текущий Activity. Как бы это реализовать?

Как я представляю, нужно, чтобы в каждом активити был код, который отвечает непосредственно за отображение этого алерта, а дальше какое-то взаимодействие на уровне листенеров с классом HttpLoader. Это вообще верное направление?

Comment: В HttpLoader передавайте контекст, а там уже из него делайте AlertDialog.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, есть риск словить java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager. Особенно, если использовать еще и ProgressDialog. То есть активити уже закрыли, а загрузчик все еще пытается работать с диалогом на этом активити.

Comment: Что мешает вызвать `mAlert.dismiss();` в `onDestroy()` активити?

Comment: Так алерт вызывался из лоадера, активити о нем и не знает. Опять-таки, хотелось бы избежать прописывания кода под это в каждом активити, хочется изящного решения.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `Service`. И свой `Context` есть, и позволит без труда организовать взаимодействие с потоком, осуществляющим сетевые операции.

Comment: Ну ведь из сервиса просто так AlertDialog не откроешь. Можно, конечно, динамически создать Activity для этого... Вы это имеете ввиду?

Comment: > Ну ведь из сервиса просто так AlertDialog не откроешь.

Почему это?

Answer (score 0):

есть удобные либы типа
http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

в коллбэке `AsyncHttpResponseHandler`  можно легко сделать твою задачу

Comment: Ну такой вариант я могу и в своем классе реализовать. Минус в том, что придется таскать код отображения алерта по всем активити так или иначе, плюс прописывать этот коллбэк при каждом обращении к сети. Может быть можно как-то изящнее решить проблему?